# Integrating Webpack with Auth0 or how to add additional Node.js modules to IBM Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, webpack, ibm-cloud, auth0, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up my nodejs backend functions to use Auth0 for IAM services.

I can successfully deploy functions to my IBM Cloud account that don't uses auth0 library, but if I try to upload a function that uses auth0 library I receive the following error:

> error: Unable to create action 'function_name': The request content
> was malformed: Unexpected end-of-input at input index 1394034 (line 1,
> position 1394035), expected '"':

I've tried to use externals in my webpack.config.js file:

```
// webpack.config.js
externals: {
    auth0: "commonjs auth0"
}

// mycode.js
const ManagementClient = require('auth0').ManagementClient;
```

and I can successfully deploy the function but when I call the endpoint I receive this error:

> (0 , r(...).ManagementClient) is not a constructor

- I'm using webpack v5.0.0 and tried also with v4.x.x
- Auth0 library:
  https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article: [Adding extra npm modules to IBM Cloud Functions with Docker](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/adding-extra-npm-modules-to-ibm-cloud-functions-with-docker-fabacd5d52f1)

Basically if I understand your question right, you need an additional package that is not included in the IBM Cloud Functions base image. The packages that are included by default are listed [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-runtimes#node-js-packages). But auth0 is not part of the list.

So following the blog post, you can create a Dockerfile.

```
FROM ibmfunctions/action-nodejs-v10 
RUN npm install auth0
```

Build the image (assuming you have a docker build environment and a working Docker account) and push it to Dockerhub:

```
docker build -t your_docker_username/action-nodejs-v10-auth0 .
docker tag your_docker_username/action-nodejs-v10-auth0:latest your_docker_username/action-nodejs-v10-auth0:0.0.1
docker push your_docker_username/action-nodejs-v10-auth0:0.0.1
```

Now you can create a source.js file containing

```
var ManagementClient = require('auth0').ManagementClient;
```

and the rest of your code.

```
ibmcloud fn action update myAuth0Function --docker your_docker_username/action-nodejs-v10-auth0:0.0.1 source.js
```

I hope this works for you. I have corrected some typos in this post and tested it. It worked so far that I was able to use the auth0 module in the action code.